# Cross Entropy in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss

Cross entropy formula:

[image]

But why does the following give `loss = 0.7437` instead of `loss = 0` (since `1*log(1) = 0`)?

```python
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

output = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([0,0,0,1])).view(1, -1)
target = Variable(torch.LongTensor([3]))

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = criterion(output, target)
print(loss)
```

Comment: Just increase the the output tensor to: `output = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([0,0,0,100])).view(1, -1)` and you get your 0.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In your example you are treating output `[0, 0, 0, 1]` as probabilities as required by the mathematical definition of cross entropy.  But PyTorch treats them as outputs, that don’t need to sum to `1`, and need to be first converted into probabilities for which it uses the softmax function.

So `H(p, q)` becomes:

```
H(p, softmax(output))
```

Translating the output `[0, 0, 0, 1]` into probabilities:

```
softmax([0, 0, 0, 1]) = [0.1749, 0.1749, 0.1749, 0.4754]
```

whence:

```
-log(0.4754) = 0.7437
```

Comment: Great answer, but is there any loss functions available in pytorch that does compute the loss like what's described in the original question?

Comment: @KevinLing Yes! NLLLoss does the same thing as CrossEntropyLoss without the softmax.

Comment: isn't it `H(p, log_softmax(output))`? Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

Your understanding is correct but pytorch doesn't compute [**cross entropy**](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) in that way. Pytorch uses the following formula.

```
loss(x, class) = -log(exp(x[class]) / (\sum_j exp(x[j])))
               = -x[class] + log(\sum_j exp(x[j]))
```

Since, in your scenario, `x = [0, 0, 0, 1]` and `class = 3`, if you evaluate the above expression, you would get:

```
loss(x, class) = -1 + log(exp(0) + exp(0) + exp(0) + exp(1))
               = 0.7437
```

Pytorch considers natural logarithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was very helpful to me!

So there is no way then reaching zero with CE loss?

Comment: @MBT you can use NLLLoss instead.

Answer (score 19):

I would like to add an important note, as this often leads to confusion.

**Softmax is not a loss function**, nor is it really an activation function. It has a very specific task: It is used for multi-class classification to normalize the scores for the given classes. By doing so we get probabilities for each class that sum up to **1**.

**Softmax is combined with Cross-Entropy-Loss** to calculate the loss of a model.

Unfortunately, because this combination is so common, it is often abbreviated. Some are using the term **Softmax-Loss**, whereas PyTorch calls it only **Cross-Entropy-Loss**.

Answer (score 8):

> The combination of `nn.LogSoftmax` and `nn.NLLLoss` is equivalent to using
> `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`. This terminology is a particularity of PyTorch, as the
> `nn.NLLoss` [sic] computes, in fact, the cross entropy but with log probability predictions as inputs where `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` takes scores (sometimes called *logits*). Technically, `nn.NLLLoss` is the cross entropy between the Dirac distribution, putting all mass on the target, and the predicted distribution given by the log probability inputs.

- [Deep Learning with PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf)

PyTorch's `CrossEntropyLoss` expects unbounded scores (interpretable as logits / log-odds) as input, not probabilities (as the CE is traditionally defined).