# manually computing cross entropy loss in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am trying to compute cross_entropy loss manually in Pytorch for an encoder-decoder model.

I used the code posted here to compute it: [Cross Entropy in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390842/cross-entropy-in-pytorch/65377793)

I updated the code to discard padded tokens (-100). The final code is this:

```
class compute_crossentropyloss_manual:
    """
    y0 is the vector with shape (batch_size,C)
    x shape is the same (batch_size), whose entries are integers from 0 to C-1
    """
    def __init__(self, ignore_index=-100) -> None:
        self.ignore_index=ignore_index
    
    def __call__(self, y0, x):
        loss = 0.
        n_batch, n_class = y0.shape
        # print(n_class)
        for y1, x1 in zip(y0, x):
            class_index = int(x1.item())
            if class_index == self.ignore_index:  # <------ I added this if-statement
                continue
            loss = loss + torch.log(torch.exp(y1[class_index])/(torch.exp(y1).sum()))
        loss = - loss/n_batch
        return loss
```

To verify that it works fine, I tested it on a text generation task, and I computed the loss using pytorch.nn implementation and using this code.

The loss values are not identical:

using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`:

[image]

Using the code from the link above:

[image]

Am I missing something?

I tried to get the source code of `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` but I wasn't able. In this link [nn/functional.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py#L2955) at line 2955, you will see that the function points to another cross_entropy loss called `torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss`; I can't find this function in the repo.

**Edit:**

I noticed that the differences appear only when I have `-100` tokens in the gold.

Demo example:

```
y = torch.randint(1, 50, (100, 50), dtype=float)
x = torch.randint(1, 50, (100,))

x[40:] = -100
print(criterion(y, x).item())
print(criterion2(y, x).item())
> 25.55788695847976
> 10.223154783391905
```

and when we don't have `-100`:

```
x[40:] = 30 # any positive number
print(criterion(y, x).item())
print(criterion2(y, x).item())
> 24.684453267596453
> 24.684453267596453
```

Comment: `torch._C` is the C source. So you could look in [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0a07488ed2c47765e337e290bd138c0e6e459cbd/aten/src/ATen/native/LossNLL.cpp)

Comment: Thanks @Chrispresso. I am not able to understand anything in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating the code. I discarded before the `-100` tokens (the if-statement above), but I forgot to reduce the hidden_state size (which is called `n_batch` in the code above). After doing that, the loss numbers are identical to the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` values. The final code:

```
class CrossEntropyLossManual:
    """
    y0 is the vector with shape (batch_size,C)
    x shape is the same (batch_size), whose entries are integers from 0 to C-1
    """
    def __init__(self, ignore_index=-100) -> None:
        self.ignore_index=ignore_index
    
    def __call__(self, y0, x):
        loss = 0.
        n_batch, n_class = y0.shape
        # print(n_class)
        for y1, x1 in zip(y0, x):
            class_index = int(x1.item())
            if class_index == self.ignore_index:
                n_batch -= 1
                continue
            loss = loss + torch.log(torch.exp(y1[class_index])/(torch.exp(y1).sum()))
        loss = - loss/n_batch
        return loss
```

Comment: Note also that the [torch implementation for softmax](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7541c9f8be0d46444adf6073051b6c7d0da4ac65/torch/csrc/jit/tensorexpr/operators/softmax.cpp#L9) is bit different to avoid overflows.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this too - thank you for the manual Cross Entropy Loss code.  It matches the pytorch results perfectly (with my data).  I have one little fix to your fix above.  In the end you need to divide by the final count of non-ignored rows (those without label -100). So you need a counter:

```
class compute_crossentropyloss_manual:
    """
    y0 is the vector with shape (batch_size,C)
    x shape is the same (batch_size), whose entries are integers from 0 to C-1
    """
    def __init__(self, ignore_index=-100) -> None:
        self.ignore_index=ignore_index
    
    def __call__(self, y0, x):
        loss = 0.
        n_batch, n_class = y0.shape
        # print(n_class)
        cnt = 0             # <----- I added this
        for y1, x1 in zip(y0, x):
            class_index = int(x1.item())
            if class_index == self.ignore_index:
                continue
            loss = loss + torch.log(torch.exp(y1[class_index])/(torch.exp(y1).sum()))
            cnt += 1        # <----- I added this
        loss = - loss/cnt   # <---- I changed this from nbatch to 'cnt'
        return loss
```